# Excel VBA User-Defined Function returns integer instead of double

Tags: excel, vba, function

I've got a function that is supposed to construct and return the average of numerical values in an array. However, while I can have the correct average printed to the Immediate Window, the value output by my function drops the numbers beyond the decimal point. The code below is truncated. I tried having all relevant values be the same type (I tried Double and Variant), casting the variables with CDbl(*x*), and converting the quotient to a String and using Format(*x*,"##.000"), but those were unsuccessful. Any help is appreciated.

```
Public Function BASELINEFILLS(serial_col As range, fill_col As range, cryo_color As Integer) As Double
Dim sum As Double
Dim vessel_length As Long                   'vessel_length is the length of the array

...

For i = LBound(vessel_data) To UBound(vessel_data)
        sum = sum + vessel_data(i).FillNumber
        Debug.Print sum                     'Prints correct sum
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print vessel_length               'Prints correct array length
    Debug.Print sum / vessel_length         'Prints correct quotient: 17.105
    
    BASELINEFILLS = sum / vessel_length     'Prints incorrect quotient: 17
End Function
```

Comment: Did you check the formatting of the cell with the UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Function` returns it's value in the format which is defined in the `As` clause of the declaration line of the function. If the data type is different when assigned to the function's name a `Type mismatch` error is generated. In the calling statement of the function the result is stored in the format the variable (which gets the value) is declared. e.g.

```
Function mysqr(a As Double) As Double
mysqr=Sqr(a)
End Function

Sub caller()
Dim s As Integer
s=mysqr(8)
End Sub
```

In this code the returned value is `Double` but then implicitly convert to `Integer`.

So to your code, the returned value is surely a `Double`, but later in the code where the function was called there is an instruction which implicitly convert the value to integer, or the type of the variable remain `Double`, but the displaying format is configured to show the result as it is viewed.

Comment: I checked through the remainder of the code in the program, and sure enough I was calling it to an Integer variable. Thanks for the help!